# How to add category image to module mod_article_categories

Tags: module, template-override

How can I add the category image to the categories listed using the J3.3.1 core module **mod_articles_categories**?

I think I have to create a module override in `template/my-template//html/mod_articles_categories/` folder, but what are the code changes I have to make?

Comment: Yes, an override will be required....what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the template override file /html/mod_articles_categories/default_items.php I added the code

`<img src="<?php echo $item->getParams()->get('image') ?>" width="40" height="40" border="0"/>`

just after this line:

`<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id)); ?>">`

That did the trick.

Offcourse the category image has to be set for each category shown, otherwise no image will display.

Comment: You can add a small PHP `if` condition to check if the category image is available, in order to avoid an empty `<img>` tag: 
`<?php if ($item->getParams()->get('image')) { ?><img src="<?php echo $item->getParams()->get('image') ?>" width="40" height="40" border="0"/> <?php } ?>`

Answer (score 1):

If you add an image to your category description, and set the module parameter "Category Description" to yes, the description (if any) AND the image will be displayed in your module without any overrides.

If you need to add the category image somewhere else (e.g. above the title), you could try this in your override file `template/my-template/html/mod_articles_categories/`:

```
<?php
  $string = $item->description;
    $beg = substr($string,strpos($string,"<img"),strlen($string));
    //$catimg = substr($beg,0,$pos_srch = strpos($beg,">"));
    $catimg = substr($beg,0,$pos_srch = strpos($beg,">"));
  echo $catimg;
?>
```

This will echo the first image from the category description, including the `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stored image path  within your override using `$item->getParams()->get('image')`
From there it should be easy to put that path into an `img` tag.

Comment: `$item->getParams()->get('image')` did not work for me, it returns nothing.

Comment: It only will return something if you actually have defined an image for the category in the categorys options tab.
It will not detect an image in the description.

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right. I forgot that option.